# PJSUA running on Raspberry Pi 3 hit Segmentation fault when stopping video stream

Tags: segmentation-fault, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3, sdl-2, pjsip

I've been building PJSIP 2.7.1 on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with OS Raspbian Stretch Lite. Video is needed so V4L2, SDL2, and OpenH264 are all built and installed. When I ran PJSUA on RPi calling another softphone with video enabled, everything went well, both audio and video were working. Every time when hangup it gave Segmentation fault though.

The RPi was used without a UI, I was ssh-ing to it for all the builds/runs. Camera is a Raspberry Pi Camera Module v2.

Here is a snippet of info from "gdb" backtrace when stopping the video call and the segfault came up. I also tried sample "vid_streamuntil" and it gave segfault as well when quitting. The same setup on Raspian Jessie Lite gave no difference.

Anyone have a clue what the problem could be? Could it be something with SDL, since segfault happened when stopping the SDL video stream? Struggling with this for days, any comments are appreciated.

> 21:53:22.897    pjsua_app.c  ......Call 0 is DISCONNECTED [reason=200
>   (Normal call clearing)]
>
> 21:53:22.898 pjsua_app_comm  ......
>
> [DISCONNCTD] To: sip:100@10.0.1.16;tag=nSgBRrGkco4MC2Y00HkhCS0M1xWbDNpH
>
> ```
> Call time: 00h:00m:08s, 1st res in 1349 ms, conn in 2083ms
>
> #0 audio PCMU @8kHz, sendrecv, peer=10.0.1.16:16438
>
>    SRTP status: Not active Crypto-suite: 
>
>    RX pt=0, last update:00h:00m:04.400s ago
>
>       total 201pkt 32.1KB (40.2KB +IP hdr) @avg=27.6Kbps/34.5Kbps
>
>       pkt loss=0 (0.0%), discrd=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reord=0 (0.0%)
>
>             (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
>
>       loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
>
>       jitter     :   0.500  14.151  20.000  14.750   4.127
>
>    TX pt=0, ptime=20, last update:00h:00m:04.301s ago
>
>       total 33pkt 5.2KB (6.6KB +IP hdr) @avg=4.5Kbps/5.6Kbps
>
>       pkt loss=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)
>
>             (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev 
>
>       loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
>
>       jitter     :   8.875   8.875   8.875   8.875   0.000
>
>    RTT msec      :   3.143   3.143   3.143   3.143   0.000
>
> #1 video H264, sendrecv, peer=10.0.1.16:11078
>
>    SRTP status: Not active Crypto-suite: 
>
>    RX pt=97, size=352x288, fps=15.00, last update:00h:00m:03.933s ago
>
>       total 151pkt 126.7KB (132.7KB +IP hdr) @avg=109.2Kbps/114.4Kbps
>
>       pkt loss=0 (0.0%), discrd=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reord=0 (0.0%)
>
>             (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
>
>       loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
>
>       jitter     :   0.800  18.716  25.311  21.577   4.489
>
>    TX pt=97, size=720x480, fps=15.00, last update:00h:00m:04.235s ago
>
>       total 323pkt 279.3KB (292.2KB +IP hdr) @avg=240.7Kbps/251.8Kbps
>
>       pkt loss=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)
>
>             (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev 
>
>       loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
>
>       jitter     :   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
>
>    RTT msec      :   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
> ```
>
> 21:53:22.898  pjsua_media.c  ......Call 0: deinitializing media..
>
> 21:53:22.898  pjsua_media.c  ........Media stream call00:0 is
>   destroyed
>
> 21:53:22.898    pjsua_vid.c  ........Stopping video stream..
>
> 21:53:22.903     v4l2_dev.c  .........Stopping v4l2 video stream mmal
>   service 16.1
>
> [Thread 0x6f2a2450 (LWP 2187) exited]
>
> 21:53:24.006    pjsua_vid.c  .........Window 1: destroying..
>
> 21:53:24.006     v4l2_dev.c  ..........Stopping v4l2 video stream mmal
>   service 16.1
>
> 21:53:24.006     vid_port.c  ..........Closing mmal service 16.1..
>
> 21:53:24.006     v4l2_dev.c  ..........Stopping v4l2 video stream mmal
>   service 16.1
>
> 21:53:24.006     v4l2_dev.c  ..........Destroying v4l2 video stream
>   mmal service 16.1
>
> 21:53:24.007      sdl_dev.c  ..........Stopping sdl video stream
>
> 21:53:24.007     vid_port.c  ..........Closing SDL renderer..
>
> 21:53:24.007      sdl_dev.c  ..........Stopping sdl video stream
>
> 21:53:24.068      sdl_dev.c !.........Stopping sdl video stream
>
> 21:53:24.068    pjsua_vid.c  .........Window 0: destroying..
>
> 21:53:24.068      sdl_dev.c  ..........Stopping sdl video stream
>
> 21:53:24.069     vid_port.c  ..........Closing SDL renderer..
>
> 21:53:24.069      sdl_dev.c  ..........Stopping sdl video stream
>
> [Thread 0x6fecf450 (LWP 2186) exited]
>
> Thread 4 "pjsua-armv7l-un" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation
>   fault.
>
> [Switching to Thread 0x757c9450 (LWP 2164)]
>
> 0x7004bb28 in ?? ()
>
> (gdb) bt
>
> #0  0x7004bb28 in ?? ()
>
> #1  0x76f2c4e0 in GLES2_DestroyTexture (renderer=, texture=0x74e04098)
>
> at /home/pi/sdl2/SDL2-2.0.7/src/render/opengles2/SDL_render_gles2.c:931
>
> #2  0x76f23f3c in SDL_DestroyTexture_REAL (texture=0x74e04098) at /home/pi/sdl2/SDL2-2.0.7/src/render/SDL_render.c:2064
>
> #3  0x000b3778 in sdl_destroy ()
>
> #4  0x000b37ac in sdl_destroy_all ()
>
> #5  0x000b3a30 in job_thread ()
>
> #6  0x0011fa84 in thread_main ()
>
> #7  0x76bd7fc4 in start_thread (arg=0x757c9450) at pthread_create.c:335
>
> #8  0x76a49c68 in ?? () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/clone.S:76 from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
>
> Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt
>   stack?)
>
> (gdb)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the Solution!
Just Need to set SDL_VIDEODRIVER and SDL_RENDER_DRIVER to matching device!

For example I set SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy SDL_RENDER_DRIVER=software

Your Welcome!